# Calling variables to run scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that lists all files in a directory, lists them in alphabetical order, and places the number of the file before the filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1
cd ~/bin

for f in *
do
    if [ -f $f ]; then
        echo "$x: $f"
        declare a$x=$f
        x=$(expr $x + 1)
    fi
done

read -p "What would you like to execute?: " num
$num
```

Output would be

```
1: file0
2: file1
3: file2
```

etc

Running $num will execute the command

```
a1
```

which is not a command. What I want to do is run what $a1 is equal to (ie file0). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the eval command:

```
eval \$a0
```

Hope this helps =)

EDIT: Fixed missing backslash

Comment: Thanks Janito! That worked, except I needed to modify it like:

`eval \$a$(echo $num)`

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the observation! Could you consider accepting the answer, please? =)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are implementing the `select` built-in command:

```
PS3="What would you like to execute?: "
select cmd in *; do
    $cmd
    break
done
```